# Is there any real time GALILEO coverage map?

Tags: galileo

GLONASS has [this](https://www.glonass-iac.ru/GLONASS/CumulativeAvailability.php) neat live coverage map of earth:

[image]

Brief explanation:

The scale is the fraction of the current day when the 3D [dilution of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_(navigation)) or PDOP is ≤ 6. Per [this comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120152/satellite-navigation-in-mongolia#comment295179_120172) if the best precision were 7 meters, this is the fraction of the day at each point where the 3D precision would be better than 6 x 7 meters or 42 meters. That the map is almost completely clear means this is almost always met. Per [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/120172/59997) once can see a substantial improvement over [performance in 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q12nP.jpg) (from [here](https://www.oxts.com/technical-notes/what-does-glonass-add-2/)) as the constellation is populated with more satellites over time. With insufficient satellite number, low precision (high dilution of precision) is often caused by the limited number of satellites in view at the moment all being in one part of the sky.

**Question:** Are there any similar maps for GALILEO?

[image: GPS dilution of precision]

Screen shot from [here](https://www.anatumfieldsolutions.com/What-is-PDOP-And-Why-its-Obsolete_b_43.html).

Comment: I've made an edit based on the link you supplied in chat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Galileo constellation is not complete (you can check its status [here](https://www.gsc-europa.eu/system-status/Constellation-Information)), so the official coverage data doesn't seem to be published yet. According to European Space Agency, Galileo should be usable by 2020.

ESA have been performing [positioning tests](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Navigation/Galileo/Steps_so_far) of their system since 2013 which were carried out in several EU countries. According to the following plot [released in 2014](https://www.esa.int/spaceinimages/Images/2014/02/Galileo_positioning_performance), they were able to achieve a precision of 7.2 meters with 95% confidence during these tests.

[image]

ESA also offers a [website](https://www.gssf.info/GSSF%20subpage%20GSSF%20analyses%20-%20DOP.htm) where you can *simulate* the coverage and DOP of Galileo once it will be fully functional. For instance, this is how they expect the DOP of Galileo will look like:

[image]